# How to play song from Playlist

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-2.6

I am making a music player in python 2.6 with Tkinter. Here's my code :

```
from Tkinter import *
import mp3play
import tkFileDialog
import Tkinter
def open_file():                                #Opens a dialog box to open .mp3 file
  global music                                #then sends filename to file_name_label.
  global mp3
  global play_list
  filename.set (tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension = ".mp3", filetypes=[("All Types", ".*"), ("MP3", ".mp3")]))
  playlist = filename.get()
  playlist_pieces = playlist.split("/")
  play_list.set (playlist_pieces[-1])
  playl = play_list.get()
  play_list_display.insert(END, playl)
  mp3 = filename.get()
  print mp3
  music = mp3play.load(mp3)
  pieces = mp3.split("/")
  name.set (pieces[-1])

def play():                                     #Plays the .mp3 file
  music.play()

def stop():                                     #Stops the .mp3 file
  music.stop()                
def pause():                                    #Pauses or unpauses the .mp3 file
  if music.ispaused() == True:
     music.unpause()
  elif music.ispaused() == False:
     music.pause()

def vol(event):                                 #Allows volume to be changed with the slider
  v = Scale.get(volume_slider)
  music.volume(v)
def Exit():
  exit()
root = Tk()
root.title("EmoPlayer")
root.geometry('300x100+250+100')
filename = Tkinter.StringVar()
name = Tkinter.StringVar()
play_list = Tkinter.StringVar()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu = filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command = open_file)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command = Exit)
root.config(menu=menubar)
open_file = Button(root, width = 6, height = 1, text = 'Open file', command = open_file)
open_file.grid(row=0, column=3)
play_button = Button(root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Play', command = play)
play_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)
stop_button = Button(root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Stop', command = stop)
stop_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = W)
pause_button = Button(root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Pause', command = pause)
pause_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
volume_slider = Scale(root, label='Volume', orient = 'horizontal', fg = 'black', command = vol)
volume_slider.grid(row=0, column=4)
file_name_label = Label(root, font=('Verdana', 8), fg = 'black', wraplength = 300, textvariable=name )
file_name_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=8)
play_list_window = Toplevel(root, height = 150, width = 100)
play_list_window.title("Playlist")
play_list_display = Listbox(play_list_window, width = 50)   
play_list_display.pack()

play_list_window.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

This code can open a mp3 file, insert it in playlist and play it. But it cant allow to play song by selecting it from playlist. Can anyone tell me how to make things work by selecting from playlist?

Comment: your indentation is all messed up in your question.

Comment: The two calls to mainloop are not needed. Since `play_list_window` has root as parent, `play_list_window.mainloop()` calls `root.mainloop()`. Thus you leave `play_list_window.mainloop()` once your master window is closed, and the second call has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to either selection changed (`"<<ListboxSelect>>"`) or double click events (`"<Double-Button-1>"`) of your listbox.

Note that you will have to store somewhere the complete path of mp3 files (the name of the file as displayed in the playlist is not enough to play it).

```
def tune_changed(event):
  idx = event.widget.curselection()[0]
  print ("Now playing %s" % event.widget.get(idx))

play_list_display.bind("<Double-Button-1>", tune_changed)
play_list_display.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", tune_changed)
```

Comment: You might want to respond differently to the two events (the selection changes for many reasons, including cursor navigation). Still, those are the two that matter for this sort of thing.

Comment: FabienAndre i tried this but now it is just mentioning the name of song in the python shell but neither playing it nor changing the name on the player audio bar ???

Comment: Here is the code to respond to a selection event, it's up to you to plug thing so that it actually play the song...